# Angular5 select model

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a Angular5 `<select>` bound to array of customers. See below:

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="record.customer_id" (ngModelChange)="setCustomer($event)" name="customer_id">
  <option *ngFor="let x of customers" [ngValue]="x.id">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In setCustomer function I get an customer's id as 'event'.

Property `record.customer_id` is type of number, not object. Is there any way how to get a whole customer entity in `setCustomer` method and also preserve binding to `record.customer_id` ?

I found on Angular docu a way `[compareWith]` so I tried:

```
<select class="form-control" [compareWith]="compareCustomer"  [ngModel]="record.customer_id" (ngModelChange)="setCustomer($event)" name="customer_id">
  <option *ngFor="let x of customers" [ngValue]="x">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and

```
compareCustomer(c1: customer, c2: number) : boolean {
   if (c1 == null || c1 == undefined) {
     return false;
   }

   if (c1.id == c2) {

     return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Does not work. When I select any option, `setCustomer` is executed, `record.customer_id` gets selected id. However, after select loses focus, selected option is reset to blank.

There is a workaround (iteration in customers array and manual match by id) that I want to avoid:

```
 setCustomer(event) {

    this.record.customer_id = Number.parseInt(event);

    customers.forEach(c => {

       if (c.id === this.record.customer_id) {

           // some logic with selected customer


       }
    });
}
```

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of bind customer_id, bind the whole object:

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="record" (ngModelChange)="setCustomer($event)" name="customer_id">
  <option *ngFor="let x of customers" [ngValue]="x">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```